# Sendgrid v3 template replace string

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am trying to replace the strings in my template[image]

To do this ive done the following:

```
section = helper.Section("%course_name%", "Tekst");
mail.addSection(section);
section = helper.Section("%user%", "Textforasubstitutiontagofsection2");
mail.addSection(section);
```

However when i recieve the mail the strings are not replace and stand as the above picture

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using `substitutions` rather than `sections` in this case. `section` tags are meant to encapsulate groups of `substitution` tags. [Docs for more info](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/section_tags.html).